# java script filling up an array so it matches following structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, jqtree

lets say i want to start with empty value of variable data, how can to achieve this result with javascript using push method:

```
var data = [
 {
      label: 'node1',
      children: [
      { label: 'child1' },
      { label: 'child2' }
        ]
      },
      {
      label: 'node2',
      children: [
      { label: 'child3' }
      ]
      }
 ];
```

i have tried:

```
data.push("label: nodel", "children:"+ ['child1', 'child2']);
```

looking at code above i need to insert one element that will be linked with list of childs. Can someone help me achieve this.. i would be very grateful.
Best regards.

Comment: `data.push({ label: 'node1', children: [{ label: 'child1' }, { label: 'child2' }]});`

Comment: this is the answer! thank you! how can i honor you here or smt.. paste your solution as answer.. and ill accept it. Thanks bunch!

Comment: just accept milkshakes answer, it's basically the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
var object1 = {
                label: 'node1',
                children: [
                    { label: 'child1' },
                    { label: 'child2' }
                    ]
                };
var data = new Array();
data.push(object1);
```

OR

```
data.push({ label: 'node1', children: [ { label: 'child1' }, { label: 'child2' } ] });
```

**EDITED TO SHOW YOSHIS VERSION ASWELL**